# Как у png изображения скруглить края на Андроид?

Tags: android, java

Всем добрый день.
Возник вопрос: мне с сервера приходят изображения в формате png, я их скачиваю и храню на устройстве. При выводе их в ImageView мне необходимо скруглить края у этого изображения. Долго гуглил, искал похожие задачи, но ничего толком не нашел, поэтому вышел с таким вопросом на вас.
Может есть примеры?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: вот это видели? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208365/create-circular-image-view-in-android   
или вот это   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все аналогичные задачи: скруглить края, добавить туману в центре, поместить в окружность, задать серо-буро-малиновые рамки в виде сердечек и проч. решаются примерно одинаково:

1. Создаем собственный класс наследующий от базового класса виджета `class MyImageView extends ImageView`
2. Перегружаем метод `protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)` - то есть рисуем наши/ваши сердечки в этом месте
3. В некоторых случаях, когда сердечки особо извращенные придется переписать метод `onMeasure()` - для корректного расчета размера сердечек
4. Можно в принципе задавать свои публичные методы для задания уровня малиновости сердечек - `setHeartColor()`, тогда придется декларировать атрибуты этих методов в файле res/values/attrs.xml, в этом случае можно напрямую задавать в XML ресурсе цвет сердечек:

---

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:heart="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/mypackage.heart"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
   <mypackage.HeartImageView
            android:id="@+id/myHeart"
            android:src="@drawable/darling"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            heart:heartColor="@color/light_magenta"
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

В общем Android предоставляет для этого практически неограниченные возможности.

Comment: Спасибо! А вот как например решить такую задачу: имеется три картинки, необходимо взять треть каждой объеденить в одну и поместить в ImageView. То есть как сделать из трех объектов Bitmap один?

Comment: 1 вопрос=1 ответ